# Polynomial division modulo 5, gcd of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I have to find the gcd $h$ of $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[X]$.

$f=X^9+X^8+X^7+X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1,$

$g=X^4+X-2.$

Here is my polynomial division:

[image]

My solution is $3X^3-X^2+3X+1$ but this is not correct, because I have to use it for further tasks and it doesn't work there. In addition, wolfram alpha says the solution in modulo 5 is $X^2+3X+1$ and I can solve the other tasks with this polynomial.

Can someone please check my polynomial division?

Comment: Doesn't strike as strange the fact that there is a $5$ in your answer?

Comment: Oops, thanks. I changed that but it's still not the right answer.

Comment: Do I have to change $g=X^4+X-2$ to $g=X^4+X+3$ at the beginning? ($-2 mod 5 = 3$)

Comment: I'd say that that would be a good idea, although it is not essential.

Comment: I've cheked it and, yes, the answer is $X^2+3X+1$. I would like to help you, but I don't understand your computations. Do you want me to show you how I did it?

Comment: You made a mistake in the last computation. The remainder should be $3X^3-X^2-2X = 3X^3+4X^2+3X$ in mod$5$. This term has the factorization $3X(X-1)^2$ in mod $5$

Comment: But the correct remainder is $X^2+3X+1$?

Comment: If someone wants to help me with my solution: I've added another comment https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3514474/742096.

Comment: Generally you should amend (or append to) your question rather than posting things like an answer. That way you can add relatively complex information that can be seen by anybody interested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- There's an error in your final step.  The result should be $\ 3x^3-x^2+3x \ $.
- You haven't completed the computation. The result  $\ 3x^3-x^2+3x \ $ is simply the *remainder* of $\ \sum_\limits{k=0}^9x^k\ $ on division by $\ x^4+x-2\ $.  You now have to find the remainder of $\ x^4+x-2\ $ on division by  $\ 3x^3-x^2+3x \ $.  Subtracting $\ 2x\left(3x^3-x^2+3x\right)\ $ from $\ x^4+x-2\ $ gives you $\ 2x^3-x^2+x-2\ $, and adding $\ 3x^3-x^2+3x \ $ to this gives you $\ 3x^2+4x-2=3(x^2+3x+1)\ $—that is, the result returned by Wolfram alpha multiplied by the unimportant factor of $3$.

This doesn't quite complete the procedure, however.  You still have to find the remainder of $\ 3x^3-x^2+3x \ $ on division by $\ x^2+3x+1\ $, which you should find to be $0$, thus telling you that $\ x^2+3x+1\ $ is the desired gcd.

Comment: Thank you! How did you come up with the 2x? I have to calculate $X^4+X-2:(3X^3-X^2+3X)$ right? But $\frac{X^4}{3X^3}$ is not $2X$?

Comment: Because you're working in $\ \mathbb{F}_5[X]\ $, $\ 3\times 2=1\  $, and $\ \frac{1}{3}=2\ $, so $\ \frac{X^4}{3X^3}\ $ *is* $\ 2X\ $ in $\ \mathbb{F}_5[X]\ $.

Comment: OK. Why is $\frac{1}{3}=2$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$? I can't quite follow that yet.

Comment: $\ 3\times2\equiv 1\pmod{5}\ $, so $\ 2\ $ is the multiplicative inverse of $3$ in $\ \mathbb{F}_5\ $.

Answer (score 0):

First I divided $X^9$ by $X^4$ and wrote $X^5$ right next to the equal sign. Then I subtracted $X^5\times (X^4+X-2)$ from $(X^9+X^8+...+X^2+X+1)$ and wrote the result below. Then the same step over and over again, i.e. dividing $X^8$ by $X^4$, adding the result to the right and multiplying it back. I did this until the degree is smaller than $X^4$. This should be the correct result, but unfortunately it is not. This should be the standard algorithm for polynomial long division (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in mod $5$, 
$$g=x^4+x-2=(x-1)^2(x^2+2x+3).$$
On the other hand, the polynomial $f$ also has $x-1$ as a factor since $f(1)=0$.
Also $f'(1)=45=0\pmod 5$. Therefore $\gcd(f,g)$ contains $(x-1)^2=x^2+3x+1$ as a factor.

Now we only need to show that $x^2+2x+3$ is not a factor of $f$.

Comment: I have to do it with polynomial long division, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: In fact no need long division. Put $x^2+2x+3=0$ or $x^2=-2x-3=3x+2$ ans substitute this value of $x^2$ in $f$ to check divisibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what the assignment says (gcd with polynomial long division).